C# .NET 8 console app works in one environment but not another
I have just upgraded a .NET framework console app to .NET 8. It works perfectly both in VS 2022, as well as on my local machine after publishing.
However, when I copy the files over to our server (Windows Server 2016 Standard 64 bit) to run from there, the .exe flashes open the console and immediately closes it with nothing actually running.
What could be the problem, or how can I find what the problem is? No actual error shows up anywhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated


Check Windows Event Logs. 2. Make the Console App write logs to a File or Windows Event Log (or wherever you want, basically).


Well it is almost impossible to say without seeing any code!  If it closes so quick, then run it from a console opened manually (navigate to the path and type in the exe name), to see if you have any output.   Or update the program to wait for a key press before closing.

Thanks @Fildor event logs pointed me in the right direction

Turns out the server was missing .net 8 Runtime. Once installed, everything worked. Windows event logs directed me to the problem.

Note that it's possible to change the packaging settings so that all necessary .NET 8 runtime DLLs are packaged along with the rest of the application, so that you don't need to have the .NET 8 runtime installed on the target machine. If you do that it does of course increase the installation size, but it reduces installation dependencies.
